# Expect not working inside my Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, expect

I am trying to execute expect command inside by small bash script to login into servers using key authentication method. My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=$1
/usr/bin/expect -c "
                    spawn ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa root@$HOST  
                    expect -exact "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': " ;
                    send "PASSPHRASE\n" ; 
                    interact
                   "
```

Output with error is:

```
spawn ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa root@server.domain.com
couldn't read file "passphrase": no such file or directory
```

Can you help to correct this?

Comment: Consider using `ssh-agent` instead of `expect`.

Comment: @jordanm  Thank you.  Can you tell me why did you suggest using ssh-agent here? and what's the purpose of using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a quoting issue in your code. Rather than trying to pass commands to `expect` on the command line save your code as an Expect script. You can then run it from a shell script or otherwise.

**script.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# usage: ./script.exp host
set HOST [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa root@$HOST  
expect -exact "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': "
send "PASSPHRASE\n"
interact
```

However, if that's all you're doing with Expect in this case I second the suggestion to use `ssh-agent` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much :) This one worked for me.
Also can you tell me why did you suggest of using ssh-agent? what's the purpose of using it.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer solved your problem click the checkbox to the left of it to accept it as the answer. As for `ssh-agent`, it can be used to avoid having to type out the passphrase for your key more than once per login session without saving that passphrase in plaintext. You can read about it at http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh.

Comment: @nwk : How to call this script.exp from the bash ? Something like this.

!#/bin/bash

cd /tmp/<script_path>
./script.exp

Comment: @ArunRaj What do you mean by "call"? If you install Expect and make the script executable with `chmod +x script.exp`, you can run it from your shell like any other executable script with `/path/to/script.exp`.

Comment: @nwk : I would like to execute the expect script from a shell script. So how should i trigger/call/invoke the expect script from the shell script ?